# MFC - Print the content of a DWORD array to log

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

How can I perform the task in subject in order to display this DWORD array content in Hex on my log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DWORD ar[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{   CString str;
    str.Format(L"%08X\n", ar[i]);
    TRACE(L"%s", str);
}
```